# Can useReducer do a functional update similar to useState?

Tags: reactjs

For `useState`, we can use a functional update so that the new state is computed using the previous state.

For example, a count increment function can be used in this way.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0)

const increment = () => {
 setState((prevState) => (prevState + 1)))
}
```

Functional update works well when there are multiple HTTP requests trying to change the state.

I was wondering if I can achieve the same thing using the `useReducer` hooks so that the updating the state is using the previous state?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I seem to made a mistake when using the `useReducer` hooks. My previous not working code is that:

```
const initialState = {count: 0};
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const increment = () =>{
 dispatch({type: 'increment', payload: {count: state.count + 1})
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: action.payload};
  }
}
```

After I changed to this, the code works

```
const initialState = {count: 0};
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const increment = () =>{
 dispatch({type: 'increment'})
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
  }
}
```

I hope this will help if anyone is facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result, you will use the `dispatch` function rather than using the state update returned from `useState`, here is an example that would achieve the same result:

```
const initialState = {
   currentCount: 0,
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {
         currentCount: state.currentCount + 1 // state has the previous value
      };
    default:
      console.error('Must implement action type: ', action.type);
  }
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'increment' })}>Increment</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just realized my mistake a few minutes ago and edited my question. I will still accept your answer.

Comment: @Boogie Ah nice, glad you got it, I just put together this sandbox, but don't think you need it anymore! https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-khayyam-8kgk0?file=/src/App.js:256-257